# error using Laravel using extends, include and yield

Tags: php, laravel

[My files are saved in resources\views\layouts as in the picture below :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uQHe.png)

The code I am using is simple discribed below :

**header.blade.php**  `<h1>Header</h1>`

**footer.blade.php**  `<h1>Footer</h1>`

**index.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.header')
@yield('center')
@include('layouts.footer')
```

**allproducts.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.index')
@section('center')
<h1>This is the center of the page</h1>
@endsection
```

**in route web.php**

`Route::get('Products', ["uses"=>"ProductsController@index"]);`

**in the controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
         return view("allproducts", compact("Products"));
    }
}
```

I always have this error: View [layout.index] not found.

I included the photo to show that my files are on the right path.

By reading the similar question and proposed solutions asked before about this problem

1. The view I am including exists in the correct folder.
2. The file within layouts directory.
3. In **allproducts.balde.php** file I wrote `@extends('layout.index')` instead `@extends('layouts.index')` as some question solved.

I spent a lot of time trying to fix this problem.

I really appreciate any help

kind regards

Comment: Look at the error, then look at point 3 again. You're still missing the `s` at the end of `layout`. Note that you have layout in both allproducts (for index) and index (for footer)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @aynber I did the same as you mentioned. But the error stays the ```View [layout.footer] not found.```

Comment: As I said, it's the exact same issue. `layout` vs `layouts`

Comment: @anyber thank you. even that the problem is not solved. add the ```s``` or remove it the same issue.

Comment: Check your controller method where you are returning the view response  - check if you have a typo there

Comment: If it still says `View [layout.something] not found`, search your files for more instances of it. It **must** be `layouts`, and it looks like you've used `layout` in several places. Keep searching. If the error says `View [layouts.something] not found`, then that's another issue. Pay attention to the s.

Comment: @Donkarnash I attached the code I used in Controller in the code.

Comment: @anyber I did what you told me. But i still have this problem. may I know please which kind of issue can be?

Comment: Okay after making the changes suggested in comments, like typos, what is the error you are now getting

Comment: @Donkarnash `View [layout.footer] not found.` I still have this error

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear` from the terminal and also check if you have any @include('layout.footer') call in either `allproducts.blade.php` or any of it's included views or in `/layouts/index.blade.php`

Comment: @Donkarnash I cleared the view using the command you gave me. I don't know how but the problem is solved. I checked the included file and everything in the code is okay. even my problem solved but I am confused about what was exactly the problem. I tried to add `s` and remove it as the guys mentioned but the error was the same. otherwise Thank you so much. you really help me

Answer (score 1):

> @Donkarnash I cleared the view using the command you gave me. I don't know how but the problem is solved. I checked the included file and everything in the code is okay. even my problem solved but I am confused about what was exactly the problem. I tried to add s and remove it as the guys mentioned but the error was the same. otherwise Thank you so much. you really help me

Laravel caches the compiled views. These views are compiled from the blade files which the developer creates.

Sometimes when developer makes some minor changes - like in your case you just added 's' to layout making it layouts - are not picked up by Laravel, the compiled views are not updated i.e. recompiled and cached again.

So at times when you get an error regarding blade views and even after changing/rectifying the error if you still get the same error message - you must clear the cached views by running from the terminal

```sh
php artisan view:clear
```

When you clear the cached views, Laravel recompiles the views from blade files and then caches them

Answer (score 0):

If you had a typo in your views, probably you have a typo in your route file

Comment: That what I was thinking in. But I didn't know how to fix it. I tried many time to modified the code but always an error in view. I tried also to delete cache:clear but without any progress.

Comment: Try to follow the data. You start with a get request in your browser so it goes to your web routes file, then it goes to your controller file, make sure you have the correct route and the right path to the view in the controller

Comment: @paroCham in the Controller that what I have `<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    { 
         return view("allproducts", compact("Products"));  
    }
}`